# What would be some Japanese Buddhist/Shinto routines or rituals that households will do?

Tags: personal-practice, rituals

I believe in all the religions holding stake in the world but I am more attuned with Japanese Buddhism and Shintoism. I've read through a lot of info on the two and love the harmony between them. I also enjoy the Shinto legends and in a way believe in the life force or kami of the world around me. I understand that a majority of these religions are trying to find the happiness and the peace within yourself and in your life. Respecting nature too.

My question comes from wanting to know if there is anything that I could insert into my daily life that would help me... feel more at peace I guess. I watch and read a lot about Japanese culture, but I can't really seem to find any info for little routines or actions that I've seen portrayed in media.

For instance, Charms hanging from the windows/doorways. Little shrines to meditate in front of in the house.

Are there more of these that aren't explained due to them being so minor? Are there special statues or paintings that hold any meanings? Maybe sayings? Plants? Smells?

Recently, I've started caring for plants more...in-particular, a bonsai that I am hoping will be beautiful and something I can pass on to my children.

I use incense which helps me think about my life and introspect.

Comment: There is an attachment to rituals and paraphernalia in your approach. I'd like to state that while it is okay to ask around about such things, this kind of attachment may slowly fade and tend to make you lose interest.

Comment: A lot of the things that I do in my life I try to do in a way to be.. peaceful. I try to keep thought and effort into my actions knowing that it effects the future. I mostly am just curious about how others do similarly to what I do. I don't go out of my way to do my habits but it's apart of me. I don't know if that makes sense..lol but That is what I try to do @BlackFlam3

Answer (score 1):

This [article about Buddhism in Japan](http://www.buddhanet.net/nippon/nippon_partII.html) mentions visiting temples, having an altar, saying grace, and greetings.

Some traditional Japanese arts have Buddhist influences or applications: including [flower arranging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ikebana#History) and [gardens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_rock_garden#Zen_Buddhism_and_the_Muromachi_Period_.281336-1573.29) -- and [calligraphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitsuzend%C5%8D).

A [zafu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zafu).

Comment: I love the article! That is a lot of info and I forgot about the Daruma dolls as one of the off hand things I've seen in media. It's things like that that I really want to know.

The zafu is interesting too! And the way that zabuton and futon are realated. :)